# Google API for Ruby: Getting "rate-limited" without exceeding limit?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client, google-api-webmasters

I am using Google API library for Ruby to read data. The access is restricted to the IP addresses I use. The API is restricted to two endpoints. The rate usage in the console says I am at 8% of the quota limit.

However, since last week (when I did a lot of development and queried the API a lot, but like I said in total it amounted to 8% of the limit) I am apparently getting "rate-limited".

When I query the API now, I will not get an error, I will get a valid response but without the data. If I keep querying, maybe once in 5-10 requests will succeed (return data).

What is the problem? I checked the console and just cannot find anything.

I am using a command line script as described in my older question: [How to use auth token in Google API (Ruby) WebmastersV3 (service account access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486977/how-to-use-auth-token-in-google-api-ruby-webmastersv3-service-account-access)

Comment: Pleas edit your question and include the exact error message you aregetting there are a lot of quota errors we need to know exactly which one you are getting.

Comment: @DaImTo I am not getting ANY error message, like I wrote in my question - that is the problem. The API returns a response WITHOUT ANY ERROR MESSAGE, but the data is empty. If I resubmit the SAME QUERY, I will at some point get the data I am querying for. So the issue is I am not getting consistent data for the same query submitted.

Comment: Then what makes you think you are getting rate limited.  If you were getting rate limited you would see the rate limit error message.   If there is no error message then your not being rate limited.  Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DalmTo The first thing that made me think that I am rate-limited was that the problem appeared after two days of heavy querying. Before that I was using the code for several weeks without this issues. Then I searched stackoverflow and found in comments that someone (who does get the rate limit error) mentions that "I've found that the stated quotas don't really seem to be the quotas." (From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497821/webmasters-api-quota-limits?rq=1) From which I deduced that if the stated quotas are bogus, maybe the error responses are also bogus.

Comment: So what can be the issue here. I am stuck in Vietnam due to the plague, at times I cannot even pull from my own repository because bot attacks from here are rampant. When I query from public VPN, I do receive data in 1 of 3ish times, which is more often than from my real IP. I am just trying to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: If your getting no data back its because there is no data to get.

Comment: I am getting data. In one of x queries, where x is between 3 and 10, depending on my IP location, and where query is constant.